# $scope.$watch callback executes after a delay

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
$scope.$watch('duration.dayPreference',function(value){
        console.log(value);
        if(value=='every')
        {
             that.duration.days = 1;
        }
        else if(value=='selected')
        {
            //alert('test');
            that.duration.days=[];
        }
        else if(value=='everyday')
        {
            that.duration.days='everyday';
        }

    });

    this.selectDay = function (day) {
        $scope.duration.dayPreference = 'selected';
        //$scope.$apply();
        /*if(typeof(this.duration.days)!='object')
        {
            this.duration.days=[];
        }*/

        var index = this.duration.days.indexOf(day);
        if (index == -1) {
            //alert('test2');
            this.duration.days.push(day);
        }
        else {
            this.duration.days.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
```

In this, when I do `$scope.duration.dayPreference = 'selected';` I expect the line below it to have the this.duration.days set to a blank array. But it doesn't. Upon a closer inspection, I found that the callback in the $watch runs after the line below the assignment.

It may be very probable that, $watch may be using some kinda timers internally. What should be the way to do it then.

Answer (score 1):

The watch won't be triggered until the digest is run. This will be after your entire function is compete.

If you consider that AngularJS is itself written in JavaScript, there would be no way for it to react to your setting of a property at the time. You are using the thread yourself. It can only wait for you to finish and then react.

As for what to do instead...
Perhaps you could call that watch function manually?
Or maybe the code which expects the empty array should belong inside the watch?

Answer (score 0):

Watch will trigger on the `$digest`, which will occur after current cycle/code finishes running. You need to figure out a way of rearranging your code that handles things asynchronously. One possible quick solution might be:

```
var selectedDays = [];
$scope.$watch('duration.dayPreference',function(value){
    console.log(value);
    if(value=='every')
    {
         that.duration.days = 1;
    }
    else if(value=='selected')
    {
        //alert('test');
        that.duration.days = selectedDays;
    }
    else if(value=='everyday')
    {
        that.duration.days='everyday';
    }

});

this.selectDay = function (day) {
    $scope.duration.dayPreference = 'selected';

    var index = selectedDays.indexOf(day);
    if (index == -1) {
        //alert('test2');
        selectedDays.push(day);
    }
    else {
        selectedDays.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: (Notice that the `that.duration.days` Array, `selectedDays` is created once, not created anew every time `dayPreference` changes. Instead the old Array is "remembered", and will contain whatever contents you've placed in it.)